# Thinkof Python Chaper6，exercise8

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> def gcd(m,n):
        if m%n==r and n !=0 and r !=0:
            return gcd(m,n)==gcd(n,r)
        elif n==0 or r==0:
            return gcd(m,0)==1
        else:
            print None
```

> > > gcd(5,6)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
gcd(5,6)
File "<pyshell#34>", line 5, in gcd
return gcd(m,0)==1
File "<pyshell#34>", line 2, in gcd
if m%n==r and n !=0 and r !=0:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Sorry I just modified it to another version, but still got similar error message...
Many thanx to you all!

Comment: Can gou please fix the code indentations?

Comment: What's going on is that you have a bunch of invalid python. You need to sort out your indenting, and the random backticks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you changed your code pasted from `gcd(5,0)` to `gcd(5,6)` when posting this question.

Your call to `gcd` is passing the values `5` and `0`, as indicated by your error message. The line `if m%n==r:` is attempting to perform division by 0 - a mathematical impossibility. That is the reason for your `ZeroDivisionError` exception

Edit:

Formatting is off so I missed this on first pass, but in the line `r=int()` you are setting `r` to 0. That means this line `return gcd(m,n)==gcd(n,r)` is passing 0 to `gcd`.

Comment: The first call secedes but r is not assigned. So the second call is interpreted as gcd(5,0).

Answer (score 0):

The scalar r is not assigned when gcd() calls itself. This result is a zero for the second parameter. Thus the subsequent division fails.

<strike>The second line should probably be 'if m%n=r'</strike>